# Amazon RDS connection issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am new to using Amazon RDS, I have created a mySQL database and publicly accessible is set to yes. However, when I set my inbound rules to accept my laptops ip, it cannot connect. If I set it to 0.0.0.0(accept all) I can connect. So I know everything else is set up right. I just don't want to keep the rules accepting all for security. Any thoughts what I might be missing?

To set the inbound rule, I use the 'My ip' option when setting source. Port and endpoint are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this issue by realizing I had apple private relay turned on. My ip and the ip trying to access the db were different. I disabled the private relay, updated the inbound rules to my actual ip and it worked perfectly. leaving this question up in case anyone runs into the same issue.